# Delaying execution with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, dom-events

JavaScript's time out function is:

```
setTimeout(fun, 3600);
```

but what if I don't want to run any other function. Can I do `setTimeout(3600);` ?

Comment: Huh if you aren't running another function what do you need the timeout for?

Comment: If nothing is to run at the end of the timer, why are you creating a timer at all?  A little more context of your overall goal would be helpful here.

Comment: If you're hoping to do this to make javascript "sleep", timeouts don't pause execution.

Comment: It's actually setTimeout(function, millis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. If you want nothing to happen after the period of time, why do you need a `setTimeout()` in the first place?

Answer (score 11):

Based on what you are saying you are simply trying to delay execution within a function.

Say for example you want to run an alert, and after 2 more seconds a second alert like so:

```
alert("Hello")
sleep
alert("World")
```

In javascript, the only 100% compatible way to accomplish this is to split the function.

```
function a()
{
alert("Hello")
setTimeout("b()",3000);
}
function b()
{
alert("World");
}
```

You can also declare the function within the setTimeout itself like so

```
function a()
{
  alert("Hello");
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("World");
  },3000);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` takes a function *then* a delay, also try to avoid passing strings, just `setTimeout(b, 3000);` will do.

Comment: or `setTimeout(function() { b(); }, 3000)` - for example... useful if you should want to use arguments. `setTimeout(function() { b(arg1, arg2); }, 3000)` .... also it's `setTimeout(code, delay)` not the other way around.

Comment: @Peter - That won't work unless you change the `b()` function to *return* a function to be passed to the `setTimeout()`. You're right about the order of arguments, though. :o)

Comment: @patrick - What do you mean? It seems to work for me. [ **Here's an example.** ](http://jsfiddle.net/wVGKC/) ---- Alert triggered 2s after onLoad with arguments.

Comment: @Peter - You're absolutely right. Somehow in my haste I didn't notice you were calling `b()` in an anonymous function. Don't know how I could have missed that! :o)

Comment: @patrick - That's the magic of closures and function scope (w regard to passing arguments) ;)

Comment: People like you makes Stackoverflow has meaning :))) ... thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

You could always pass a handler which does nothing:

```
setTimeout(function() { }, 3600);
```

But I can hardly imagine any scenario in which this would be useful.